# Get Facebook Fans count without tokens?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was displaying my number of fans connecting to the graph api till 1 month ago when fb changed everything...

Okey, I was reading now I need an access token but I dont know the easiest way to get it

My actual code looks as...

```
<?php 
function get_fb_data($page_id) {
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.urlencode($page_id));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
    $exec = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($exec);  
}
```

But now is returning...

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'error' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'message' => string 'An access token is required to request this resource.' (length=53)
      public 'type' => string 'OAuthException' (length=14)
      public 'code' => int 104
```

am I needing an access token and SDK?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on how to achieve this, pretty sure facebook got one of their own.

Comment: I was looking for. But I have no idea if I need sdk. It's too heavy because I am only needing fan numbers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get it from this URL

http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D355692061120689

There is a function in php called `json_decode()`. Using this with `file_get_contents()`. You can retrieve the value and echo it in PHP:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D355692061120689');

$decode = json_decode($json);

echo $decode[0]->fan_count;
?>
```

**Note** Change `355692061120689` with your page id.

FQL is deprecated. Facebook will remove FQL on (7 august 2016).

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is worth noting that this answer will break when Facebook kills FQL next year (7 august 2016)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_fql

Comment: Hm... Okey so I need install the SDK only for get fan_count?

Comment: @Daan I have mention it in my answer.

Comment: The SDK is pretty small actually, and on a server the size of those shouldn't really matter. 

If you want to make sure this works for a long time you are better of using the SDK (and Facebooks own tutorial to start up). If you are looking for a quick fix @Hassan handed you a great one.

Comment: @Apeiron why you have unaccepted my answer? Its exactly what you want. Ask new question If you want to Get Facebook Fans count with token.

Comment: Yes. I will mark as valid again. But as @Daan said I need SDK, I will learn about it then ;)

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with NO TOKEN, PAGE ID, ...

Create a file, upload it on ur FTP with the name you want. For example we call it fb-count.php

Copy and paste this following code :

```
<?php

$page_name = $_GET['page'];

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Pragma: ';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fr-fr.facebook.com/'.$page_name);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

preg_match('/>([0-9]{0,3}.?.?[0-9]{0,3}.?.?[0-9]{3}) personnes aiment/i', $contents, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

How to get fans ? https://website.com/fb-count.php?page=yourpagename

Try to not abuse request or facebook will place a captcha for blocked your ip.

All rights goes to @Elegie user

Comment: Scraping Facebook pages is not allowed; they are very likely to block this (meaning, your server IP) as soon as they discover it. This is not recommendable at all, IMHO.